# How can I use multiple databases in the same request in Cherrypy and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

My app connects to multiple databases using a technique similar to [this](http://code.google.com/p/webpyte/source/browse/trunk/webpyte/sqlalchemy_tool.py). It works so long as I don't try to access different databases in the same request. Having looked back to the above script I see they have written a comment to this end:

```
SQLAlchemy integration for CherryPy,
such that you can access multiple databases,
but only one of these databases per request or thread.
```

My app now requires me to fetch data from Database A and Database B. Is it possible to do this in a single request?

Please see below for sources and examples:

**Working Example 1:**

```
from model import meta

my_object_instance = meta.main_session().query(MyObject).filter(
    MyObject.id == 1
).one()
```

**Working Example 2:**

```
from model import meta

my_user = meta.user_session().query(User).filter(
    User.id == 1
).one()
```

**Error Example:**

```
from model import meta

my_object_instance = meta.main_session().query(MyObject).filter(
    MyObject.id == 1
).one()

my_user = meta.user_session().query(User).filter(
    User.id == 1
).one()
```

This errors with:

```
(sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'main_db.user' doesn't exist")
```

**Sources:**

```
# meta.py
import cherrypy
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# Return an Engine
def create_engine(defaultschema = True, schema = "", **kwargs):

    # A blank DB is the same as no DB so to specify a non-schema-specific connection just override with defaultschema = False
    connectionString = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8' % (
        store['application'].config['main']['database-server-config-username'],
        store['application'].config['main']['database-server-config-password'],
        store['application'].config['main']['database-server-config-host'],
        store['application'].config['main']['database-server-config-defaultschema'] if defaultschema else schema
    )
    # Create engine object. we pass **kwargs through so this call can be extended
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectionString, echo=True, pool_recycle=10, echo_pool=True, encoding='utf-8', **kwargs)

# Engines
main_engine = create_engine()
user_engine = None

# Sessions
_main_session = None
_user_session = None

# Metadata
main_metadata = MetaData()
main_metadata.bind = main_engine
user_metadata = MetaData()

# No idea what bases are/do but nothing works without them
main_base = declarative_base(metadata = main_metadata)
user_base = declarative_base(metadata = user_metadata)

# An easy collection of user database connections
engines = {}

# Each thread gets a session based on this object
GlobalSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=False))

def main_session():
    _main_session = cherrypy.request.main_dbsession
    _main_session.configure(bind=main_engine)

    return _main_session

def user_session():
    _user_session = cherrypy.request.user_dbsession
    _user_session.configure(bind = get_user_engine())

    return _user_session

def get_user_engine():

    # Get dburi from the users instance
    dburi = cherrypy.session['auth']['user'].instance.database

    # Store this engine for future use
    if dburi in engines:
        engine = engines.get(dburi)
    else:
        engine = engines[dburi] = create_engine(defaultschema = False, schema = dburi)

    # Return Engine
    return engine


def get_user_metadata():
    user_metadata.bind = get_user_engine()
    return user_metadata

# open a new session for the life of the request
def open_dbsession():
    cherrypy.request.user_dbsession = cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class
    cherrypy.request.main_dbsession = cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class
    return

# close the session for this request
def close_dbsession():
    if hasattr(cherrypy.request, "user_dbsession"):
        try:
            cherrypy.request.user_dbsession.flush()
            cherrypy.request.user_dbsession.remove()
            del cherrypy.request.user_dbsession
        except:
            pass
    if hasattr(cherrypy.request, "main_dbsession"):
        try:
            cherrypy.request.main_dbsession.flush()
            cherrypy.request.main_dbsession.remove()
            del cherrypy.request.main_dbsession
        except:
            pass

    return

# initialize the session factory class for the selected thread
def connect(thread_index):
    cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False))
    return

# add the hooks to cherrypy
cherrypy.tools.dbsession_open = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', open_dbsession)
cherrypy.tools.dbsession_close = cherrypy.Tool('on_end_resource', close_dbsession)
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start_thread', connect)
```

Comment: I don't want to 'answer' my own question but the solution seems to be to add an extra scoped_session for the other database in `connect` so it looks like `def connect(thread_index): cherrypy.thread_data.user_scoped_session_class = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False)) cherrypy.thread_data.main_scoped_session_class = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False)) return` and then reference them separately in `open_dbsession`

Answer (score 1):

You could also choose an ORM that is designed from the ground up for multiple databases, like [Dejavu](http://www.aminus.net/dejavu).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/binds.html

Basically, it suggests that you use a bind param - for each connection.  That said, this seems to be a bit of a hack.

This question has a lot more detail in the answer:

[With sqlalchemy how to dynamically bind to database engine on a per-request basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857465/with-sqlalchemy-how-to-dynamically-bind-to-database-engine-on-a-per-request-basi)

That said, both this question and the one referenced aren't the newest and sqlalchemy will probably have moved on since then.

Comment: That looks pretty good. I ended up fixing the immediate problem I was facing with this question (See my comment attached to the question) but ended up with several further problems; it's all working now but the code and explanation to go with it are far too large for StackOverflow. Multiple threads + multiple dynamic DB connections per user + set up / tear down per request = pain